# c# console application to repeat keyboard presses?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a simple macro program to repeat keyboard key presses and I am having trouble finding out how to fire a keyboard event, anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tommieb75 mentioned, don't reinvent the wheel. Just take [AutoIt3](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a simple script (i.e. it doesn't have to be C#) it would be much easier to do from VBScript with the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28VS.85%29.aspx) method.  That does exactly what you are looking for.

Edit:
Ok, so it seems there is a [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class in .NET which I will assume does the same thing.

Comment: @Jimmy: Can check out autoit if that is exactly what you are looking for...http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/ Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ConsoleKeyInfo info;
do {
    info = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if ((info.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) > 0) Console.Write("Alt+");
    if ((info.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) > 0 ) Console.Write("Control+");
    if ((info.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Shift) > 0) Console.Write("Shift+");
    Console.WriteLine(info.Key.ToString());
 } while (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library for simulating keyboard and mouse activities: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/